# “Flow of knowledge”

Tags: grammar-choice, word-request

I recently created a company called Scientiflux.
It should suggest something like “Flow of knowledge”, but what would be the grammatically correct way to express this in Latin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Fluxus scientiae* translates to "a flow[ing] of knowledge", with *scientia* being understood as a watery metaphor (cf. Pliny's *fluxus aëris*).

However, an earlier and better attested word for *fluxus* is *fluctus*, and I would actually recommend it instead. It is also amply attested in metaphorical constructions, so a construction like *fluctus scientiae* would be intelligible to an ancient audience.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful - I'm not going to change the name of the company, but it is good to now how the correct way to express this correctly

Comment: @Stefan I don't think anyone expects modern company names to be grammatically correct phrases, so I think you're all good there!

Comment: Although in fairness, *fluctus scientiae* means something closer to "knowledge wave."

Comment: @SebastianKoppehel Which is even cooler. ;) But *fluctus* can also be used for flood/flowing out, which is the more etymological meaning, as opposed to *unda*.